# How to use foreach on a list of lists that on another class

Tags: c#, list, foreach

```
public class ItemCollection
{
    List<AbstractItem> LibCollection;

    public ItemCollection()
    {
        LibCollection = new List<AbstractItem>(); 
    }

    public List<AbstractItem> ListForSearch()
    {
        return LibCollection;
    }
```

and in another class i wrote this:

```
public class Logic
{
    ItemCollection ITC;

    List<AbstractItem> List;

    public Logic()
    {
        ITC = new ItemCollection();   

        List = ITC.ListForSearch();    
    }

    public List<AbstractItem> search(string TheBookYouLookingFor)
    {
        foreach (var item in List)
        {
          //some code..
        }
```

and the list in the foreach is contain nothing
and i need to work on this list (this list is should be the same content as libcollection) for the search method

Comment: From what I see, `List` (horrible name btw) **is** the same reference as `ItemCollection.LibCollection`.

Comment: Define "contain nothing."  Is it `null`?  Or is it instantiated and just empty?  In the latter case, I don't see where you actually add anything to the list...

Comment: Item Collection is becoming useless, you use it to encapsulate the list, then you expose the list!  You either need to move the search function to ItemCollection, or get rid of item collection.

Answer (score 0):

If `ItemCollection` serves no purpose other than to own the `List<AbstractItem>`, then the class should probably be removed altogether and just use `List<AbstractItem>` instead.

If `ItemCollection` has another purpose and others shouldn't have access to the underlying `List<AbstractItem>`, it can implement`IEnumerable<AbstractItem>`:

```
class ItemCollection : IEnumerable<AbstractItem>
{
    List<AbstractItem> LibCollection;

    public ItemCollection() {
        this.LibCollection = new List<AbstractItem>();
    }

    IEnumerator<AbstractItem> IEnumerable<AbstractItem>.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.LibCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable)this.LibCollection).GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class Logic
{
    ItemCollection ITC;

    public Logic() {
        ITC = new ItemCollection();
    }

    public List<AbstractItem> Search(string TheBookYouLookingFor) {
        foreach (var item in this.ITC) {
            // Do something useful
        }
        return null; // Do something useful, of course
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may want to expose `LibCollection` directly and let other code enumerate over that:

```
class ItemCollection
{
    public List<AbstractItem> LibCollection { get; private set; }

    public ItemCollection() {
        this.LibCollection = new List<AbstractItem>();
    }
}

class Logic
{
    ItemCollection ITC;

    public Logic() {
        ITC = new ItemCollection();
    }

    public List<AbstractItem> Search(string TheBookYouLookingFor) {
        foreach (var item in this.ITC.LibCollection) {
            // Do something useful
        }
        return null; // Do something useful
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried both ways and it didn't solve this problem, i need to use 'foreach' on this list of items (LibCollection<AbstractItem>) in another Class (Logic). i thought this is more easy than it really is.
Thanks a Lot